# What is this welding tool in this video?

Tags: welding, tools

https://youtu.be/w6aUzGaXShQ?t=135

At time 2:15, what's the type of the welding tool he uses?

I have read a couple of types for welding tools but I cannot see it matches any type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out that the welding in the video is a TIG welding tool, but that's not the end as there are 3 types of TIG welders.

Scratch start, Lift/Jump start and HF(High Frequency) start.
If you'd like to know more about what the differences are, Google search will find you a lot, but here is [what I found](https://www.welding.com.au/news/view/guide-for-selecting-a-tig-welding-machine).

So how to tell what types of TIG the guy used in the video?
We can tell that by watching how he operates the welder torch.

As these 3 types of TIG names suggested, HF start TIG can initiate the electric arc without scratching or touching and lifting. So the type of TIG welder the guy used in the video is HF TIG welder. The Scratch start and Lift start TIG have different ways to initiate the electric arc to weld.

Comment: You've selected your own answer as the correct one, but the three entries you've listed are methods, not types of torches. All three methods can be performed with the typical TIG torch. As noted in your linked site, it's slightly more dependent on the type of welder, not the type of torch.

Comment: @fred_dot_u you might be correct about whether it's a type or method. But when we purchase a TIG welder, we need to pick up one particular option even though the TIG torch might be same. If I purchased a Scratch Start TIG, then I won't be able to use it as a HF TIG welding tool. So this matters a lot. So we have to be precise about what type of TIG the tool is. And price wise, the HF TIG welding tool costs much more than Scratch Start, so only mention about TIG is not precise enough. That's why I asked you what type of TIG it is.

Answer (score 3):

From what little is shown, it's a TIG welder hand torch, being used without welding rod.  One does not typically allow the tungsten tip to contact the work (2:26), as it did in the video, welding itself to the work piece. Such action is poor practice. Poor practice also includes the lack of eye and skin protection.

The shape of the hand torch will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer:

[image: TIG hand torch]

Image above courtesy of [CK Worldwide](https://www.weldingsuppliesfromioc.com/ck-worldwide-25ft-18-series-superflex-tig-torch-w-flex-head-ck18-25sf-fx), result of a search for "tig hand torch."

Comment: thanks Fred for pointing out those poor practice. Yes I agree it's a TIG welder. But there are 3 types of TIG welding. Do you know which type is it?

Comment: @ fred is too polite; Unbelievably crude/dangerous third world techniques. I got a hand sunburned (UV) watching TIG ( with a helmet ,dark eye protection and leather apron.)

Comment: @Franva, please advise of the three types of TIG welding. My search for that expression returns three types of welding, of which TIG is one. Even that is inaccurate, as oxyacetylene welding is being overlooked. TIG, MIG and stick are the electricity based welding methods of which I am familiar. Heliarc is one type of TIG welding, but that's based on the type of shielding gas.

Comment: thanks @fred_dot_u for your help. I have figured it out. I will update with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a TIG welding hand torch. This article explains it well.

https://www.alphaweld.com.au/blog/48-an-introduction-to-tungsten-inert-gas-tig-welding